# Azure VM Connection Refused

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I created a VM in Microsoft Azure with Ubuntu 20 in which I run a Tomcat Server exposed to Port 443 and 80 (redirecting to 443), Neo4j on Port 7474, and Jenkins on Port 8081.
I can't access neither of those ports, although I set all the Inbound Port Rules like this:

[image]

When I try to reach IP:PORT, I always get this:

[image]

I am kinda new to Azure. It is possible to log in to the servier via SSH in the Terminal. Can anyone help me? How can I access my Server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to access to the VMs by using SSH and looking whats going on with the logs ?!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect to a terminal by SSH:

```
ssh -i <private key path> username@ipaddress
```

If you don't config your SSH key, you can use create you password on the Azure portal.

In your VM, on the left, you have many options, and one name reset password.

[image: reset password]